# Transform JSON array and assign to single value case class with Play JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON object:

```
{realtime-accesses: [
    {realtime-access: {
        level: 2
        marketID: 1
    }},
    {realtime-access: {
        level: 4
        marketID: 3
    }}
]
}
```

I want a Scala object that looks like this:

```
RealTimeAccesses(Map(1->2,3->4))
```

This is the code Im trying to use:

```
  case class RealTimeAccesses(markets: Map[Int, Int])
  object RealTimeAccesses {
    implicit val realTimeAccessesFormatter: Format[RealTimeAccesses] = (
      (__ \ "realtime_accesses").format[List[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]].map(
        _.iterator
        .flatMap(_.values)
        .map { v => v("marketID") -> v("level") }
        .toMap).inmap(m => RealTimeAccesses(m), (m: RealTimeAccesses) => m.markets))
  }
```

However this does not work, im getting can not resolve symbol on `inmap`.

My questions are:

1. How can this transformation be done the way I want?
2. Is it possible to use `type RealTimeAccess = Map[Int,Int]` instead of a case class?

Comment: Of course it cannot resolve inmap: it is not a Scala method. What exactly do you expect "inmap" to do? 1. Do you only need to parse that JSON or do you need to write it back out again? 2. No. The library you're using requires you to specify case classes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is that `Format[A]` does not have a functor. When you call `map` on it with a function `A => B` you are getting back `Reads[B]` not a `Format[B]`.

```
val format1: Format[List[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]] = (__ \ "realtime_accesses").format[List[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]]

val format2: Reads[Map[Int, Int]] = format1.map(
  _.iterator
  .flatMap(_.values)
  .map { v => v("marketID") -> v("level") }
  .toMap
)
```

So you need to call `.inmap` immediately and do all necessary transformation inside of `inmap`.

```
(__ \ "realtime_accesses").format[List[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]].inmap(
  m => {
    val markets = m.flatMap(_.values)
      .map { v => v("marketID") -> v("level") }
      .toMap
    RealTimeAccesses(markets)
  },
  (m: RealTimeAccesses) => m.markets.map {
    case (marketID, level) =>
      Map("realtime-access" ->
        Map(
          "marketID" -> marketID,
          "level" -> level
        ))
  }.toList
)
```